# Using bootstrap-slider with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-slider

I want to use [bootrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) with jQuery UI. I am following the documentation and loaded the plugin code after loading the Bootstrap CSS and jQuery.

However, the slider is not getting initialized - the `<input>` remains as it is, and I don't see any error in browser console.

Following is the code:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />   
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slider/bootstrap-slider.css" media="all" />
        <script src="./slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
            <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // With JQuery
    $('#ex1').slider({
      formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
      }
    });

        </script>

    </body>
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The issue is that jQuery UI also has a [slider widget](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) initialized using `slider()` method, So there is a namespace collision.

If you want to use the bootstrap slider alone, you can download custom jQuery ui without the slider widget from [the download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

---

Or if you want to use both, initialize the bootstrap slider like:

```
$('#ex1').bootstrapSlider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
  }
});
```

This is because, according to the following code:

```
if($) { // line number 1192
    var namespace = $.fn.slider ? 'bootstrapSlider' : 'slider';
    $.bridget(namespace, Slider);
}
```

The author is checking whether another plugin with the name *slider* exists in the namespace, if it exists, the slider will be assigned the name *bootstrapSlider*

---

```js
$('#ex1').bootstrapSlider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
  }
});
```

```css
#ex1Slider .slider-selection {
  background: #BABABA;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://raw.githack.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/master/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/master/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" />
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. I would like to award your answer, but i can do that in 13 hours.

Comment: Hi @T J , i am facing the same problem  and i tried using ".bootstrapSlider" instead ".slider" , but nothing seems to change thus i am only left with am empty text box... Can you help me out with this?

Comment: @NishiBangar Are you using the same plugin? If so, which version? It'd be easier to check what the issue is if you can create an online demo demonstrating the issue...

Comment: @TJ , Here is the  [code sample](http://codepen.io/NishiBangar/pen/xOWrNo?editors=1011).

Comment: @NishiBangar You're using AngularJS that's a whole different issue... You should create an AngularJS **directive** (maybe there is one already) for the slider instead of trying to initialize in the controller.

Comment: @TJ , Let me see to any or create my own directive.   Appreciate your response..Thanks