# Rails 4 - bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I'm trying to setup bootstrap slider to work in my Rails 4 app.

I've been struggling for most of the past year in trying to figure out how to make it work.

I have tried every combination of html/js in this page:
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

I can't get any of them working. I don't get any console errors and I can see the div id in the chrome inspector elements window. The view rendered is just a blank container when I try to use this.

I have:

Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails'
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require html.sortable
//= require disqus_rails
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require masonry.pkgd.min
//= require multipleFilterMasonry
//= require main
//= require hammer.min
//= require jquery.animate-enhanced.min
//= require jquery.countTo
//= require jquery.easing.1.3
//= require jquery.fitvids
//= require jquery.magnific-popup.min
//= require jquery.parallax-1.1.3
//= require jquery.properload
//= require jquery.shuffle.modernizr.min
//= require jquery.sudoSlider.min
//= require jquery.superslides.min
//= require rotaterator
//= require smoothscrolljs
//= require waypoints.min
//= require wow.min
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require markerclusterer
//= require infobox
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require cocoon
//= require imagesloaded.pkgd.min
//= require isotope.pkgd.min
//= require jquery.counterup.min
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require custom.js
// require slider
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require_tree .
```

I have also tried moving bootstrap-slider to the last position after tree .

App/assets/javascripts/slider.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ex8").slider({
    tooltip: 'always'
});
```

app/views/projects/_trl.html.erb

```
 <input id="ex8" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
```

Can anyone show me where to find guidance on how to get this working. I can't understand why it's so easy for everyone else and so complicated for me.

The console doesnt show any errors with the js.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
//= require slider
```

And update `slider.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ex8").slider({
    tooltip: 'always'
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried that too. It doesnt change anything. I don't have a file called slider.js in my vendor assets

Comment: You forgot to write an ```});``` in the end of slider.js file.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of [Using bootstrap-slider with jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691018/using-bootstrap-slider-with-jquery-ui) advice, I changed the `slider.js` file to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ex8").bootstrapSlider({
    tooltip: 'always'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Turbolinks, use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load',function(){

    // With JQuery
    $("#slider").slider();
    $("#slider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
      $("#sliderSliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
    });

  });
</script>
```